# Out of memory error: assemble build task & browser sync watch

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser-sync, assemble

I'm having an issue where I have a node serve task that watches .hbs files for changes and if a change occurs triggers another node task called 'styleguide'.

This style guide build task is using the node API version of Assemble (v0.23.0).

What's happening is that over time the build task is taking longer and longer to execute until eventually falling over with an error of Out of Memory followed by a JS stacktrace.

Here is the styleguide watch part of the serve task.

```
const styleguideWatchFiles = [
    './src/templates/layouts/styleguide.hbs',
    './src/templates/styleguide/**/*.hbs',
    './src/components/styleguide/**/*.hbs'
];

//watch STYLEGUIDE
chokidar.watch(styleguideWatchFiles, {
    ignoreInitial: true
})
.on('error', error => log.error(error))
.on('all', (event, path) => {
    log.file('File Changed', path);
    run(styleguide).then(() => {
        browserSync.reload('*.html');
    }).catch(err => {
        log.error(err);
    });
});
```

Here is the styleguide build task.

```
/*eslint no-console: 0 */

/**
 * styleguide.js
 *
 * Build script for handling styleguide html templates
 * using category collections in front-matter to categorise parts of styleguide
 * with Assemble and Handlebars.
 *
 * Handlebars: http://handlebarsjs.com/
 * Assemble:   https://github.com/assemble/assemble
 *
 */

import assemble from 'assemble';
import yaml from 'js-yaml';
import plumber from 'gulp-plumber';

import log from './utils/log';
import getPageData from './utils/getPageData';
import renameExt from './utils/renameExtension';
import expand from './utils/expandMatter';

import { styleguidePathConfig as path } from '../config';

export default function styleguide() {

    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        // Create assemble instance
        let templates = assemble();

        templates.dataLoader('yml', function(str) {
            return yaml.safeLoad(str);
        });

        templates.data(path.data);

        templates.preRender(/\.(hbs|html)$/, expand(templates));

        // Create styleguide pages
        templates.task('preload', (cb) => {

            templates.partials(path.sgPartials);
            templates.layouts(path.layouts);

            // Register helpers
            templates.helpers(path.helpers);

            // Add pages
            templates.pages(path.sgPages);

            // Styleguide page data - used for building dynamic menus
            templates.data({
                coreItems: getPageData('./src/templates/styleguide/core-elements'),
                componentItems: getPageData('./src/templates/styleguide/components'),
                generalItems: getPageData('./src/templates/styleguide/general'),
                sectionItems: getPageData('./src/templates/styleguide/sections')
            });

            cb();

        });

        templates.task('styleguide', ['preload'], () => {

            // Render out the template files to 'dist/styleguide'
            return templates.toStream('pages')
                // Define our own handler for more error information.
                .pipe(plumber({
                    errorHandler: err => {
                        // If we encounter this error on a build task, kill the promise
                        if (process.argv.includes('build')) return reject(err);
                        log.error(`${err.message} in ${err.path}.`);
                    }
                }))
                .pipe(templates.renderFile())
                .pipe(plumber.stop())
                .pipe(renameExt())
                .pipe(templates.dest('dist/styleguide'));

        });

        // Run the Assemble build methods
        templates.build('styleguide', err => {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            return resolve();
        });
    });
}
```

The **getPageData** function just loops over the specified folder and builds an array of objects to be used by handlebars template to build out a dynamic menu based on the pages being compiled.

So my question is what's causing the memory leak?

Is is that every time the styleguide.js task is called on change the assemble() instance is not being garbage collected after the resolve is returned?

Do I need to be running the entire thing on watch; calling the 'preload' & styleguide tasks?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I don't know if I could point to a specific place that there's a memory leak, but if you're creating a new instance of assemble each time, then all of that should be cleared. Other places to check are in chokidar, browser-sync, js-yaml, gulp-plumber, the custom utils, or any custom helpers. I'd start by taking out pieces to try to narrow down where the biggest impact is. If you do find a memory leak in one of the assemble modules, please open an issue.

Comment: Thanks @doowb, I'll start pulling pieces out to see what's happening.

Comment: Sorry @doowb, Just so I'm sure. The dataLoader and preRender functions are required for me to be able to import external .yml files into the front matter correct?

Also, the task functions run and complete in the order specified right?

Thanks again

Comment: We recently added the `expand` part by default so that might not be necessary now. You still need to add the yaml data loader to load yaml files. Yes the tasks run in `series` by default so the dependencies will run first before the task and they'll run in the order specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the styleguide task on it's own (rather than as part of `npm start`) I saw that the promise wasn't resolving.

So the issue was a couple of things...

First of all: In the 'styleguide' task the error log that gulp plumber should have been providing me was in the wrong spot (below the reject). Pulling everything out and rebuilding it piece by piece showed me this (thanks @doowb)

Second of all: Once I had an error displaying in the console I was able to pin point what was going on. Turns out the reason the task wasn't resolving was because assemble couldn't find a reference to a partial. This led me to my config file where I was setting the partials array and it wasn't including everything I needed.

I feel so silly now but thanks for steering me on the right track.

Comment: :) when there are a lot of moving parts, sometimes it can be tough to figure out what's actually causing a problem. I usually have to step back and reduce the issue down to small pieces to find the correct error too. I'm surprised that `gulp-plumber` didn't work. Maybe the `.stop` method should be after `.dest`?

Comment: With further debugging we've found that the issue seems to be caused by the renderFile() function. Looking into memory leaks for that particular function. Going to read up on this article: https://www.dynatrace.com/blog/understanding-garbage-collection-and-hunting-memory-leaks-in-node-js/ and then utilitse Chrome dev tools. Wish me luck